Error connecting to websocket -- TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
I am trying to integrate AWS transcribe streaming in a websocket using python as a backend language. I will be sending PCM 16 bit 24kHz audio chunks as input from the client(frontend). I am not able to connect to the server.
Here is my code -
app = Flask(__name__)
client = TranscribeStreamingClient(region=<region>)
 
async def write_chunks(stream,data):
    # This connects the raw audio chunks generator coming from the microphone
    # and passes them along to the transcription stream.
    async for chunk in data:
        await stream.input_stream.send_audio_event(audio_chunk=chunk)
    await stream.input_stream.end_stream()
 
 
class MyEventHandler(TranscriptResultStreamHandler):
    def handle_transcript_event(self, transcript_event: TranscriptEvent):
        # This handler can be implemented to handle transcriptions as needed.
        results = transcript_event.transcript.results
        for result in results:
            for alt in result.alternatives:
                print(alt.transcript)
 
async def handle_client(data):
    print("Received audio")
 
    stream = await client.start_stream_transcription(
        language_code="en-US",
        media_sample_rate_hz=24000,
        media_encoding="pcm"
    )
    handler = MyEventHandler(stream.output_stream)
    # This connects the raw audio chunks generator coming from the microphone
    # and passes them along to the transcription stream.
    await asyncio.gather(write_chunks(stream,data), handler.handle_events())
 
    
async def main():
    server = await websockets.serve(handle_client, "localhost", 8282)
    await server.wait_closed()
    
asyncio.run(main()) 

I get the following error -
Received audio
connection handler failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\websockets\legacy\server.py", line 245, in handler
    await self.ws_handler(self)
  File "realtime_amazon_py.py", line 46, in handle_client
    await asyncio.gather(write_chunks(stream,data), handler.handle_events())
  File "\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\amazon_transcribe\handlers.py", line 28, in handle_events
    await self.handle_transcript_event(event)
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression


Expecting to connect to the websocket and print the transcriptions

handle_transcript_event has to be a coroutine (async def handle_transcript_event(…)).
